# Help needed with test class

Tags: unit-test, userrecordaccess

I am new to code and needed to check the UserRecordAccess in flow.

I was able to put together the below, and it actually works and let's me check the HasEditAccess in flow to then act on it.

However I have no idea what a test class for this should look like. I am tried all day and can't get it right.
Can someone help with me that?

here the apex class:

```
public class GetUserRecordEditAccess {

public class inputValues{
    @InvocableVariable (required=true)
    public String CurrentUserId;
    @InvocableVariable (required=true)
    public String CurrentRecordId;
}

@InvocableMethod 
public static List<UserRecordAccess> getRecord(List<inputValues> inputs){
    for(inputValues i : inputs){
     List<UserRecordAccess> EditAccess = new List<UserRecordAccess>();
        EditAccess = [SELECT RecordId, HasEditAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId =:i.CurrentUserId AND RecordId =:i.CurrentRecordId];
    return EditAccess;
    }
    return null;
} 

}
```

for the test class I ended up with the below but it is giving me errors that the variable CurrentUserID and CurrentRecordId do not exist as well as the getrecord method, or the method being of the wrong signature void

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class GetUserRecordEditAccessTEST {


static testMethod void TestGetUserRecordEditAccess() {

Account r = new Account (Name='test Account');
insert r;
User u = new User(FirstName='test', LastName='user');
insert u;

GetUserRecordEditAccess ura = new GetUserRecordEditAccess();
ura.CurrentUserId = u.id;
ura.CurrentRecordId = r.id;
ura.getrecord();
 }
 }
```

I know for inserting the user I will have to add all the required fields, but i can't get the other aspects right.

Comment: If you tried all day, please **[edit]** this post to include what you have attempted so far and indicate how exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Have you tried the [Trailhead module on building test classes?](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing) I don't see any System.assert that would define your code as being a test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an inputValues variable, and populate those values, then pass it in to your method. Also, static methods do not need an "instance" to execute. Here's the following revision:

```
GetUserRecordEditAccess.inputValues value = new GetUserRecordEditAccess.inputValues();
value.CurrentUserId = u.id;
value.CurrentRecordId = r.id;
List<GetUserRecordEditAccess.inputValues> values = 
    new List<GetUserRecordEditAccess.inputValues>{ value };
GetUserRecordEditAccess.getRecord(values);
```